# Take UIImage of UIViews layer property

Tags: uiimage, core-graphics, core-animation, calayer, cashapelayer

I am Adding multiple `CAShapeLayer`s to `layer` property of my `UIView` subclass by calling `[self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];`

To capture these layers in a `UIImage` I have implemented the following method which is meant to take an image of the `layer` property.

```
- (UIImage *)takeImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (context) {

        [self.layer renderInContext:context];

        UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return snapshotImage;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

My Problem is, that the resulting image is completely blank. Why is this so?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The image was great! Didn't set the IBOulet properly.